# How to add div to React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've just started my react native app and having some troubles. I have some experience with react but that doesnt seem to be helping much. The div surrounding the Text is meant to be my app header so Im trying to style it but for some reason it throws an error saying  is NOT recognised?

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';


class App extends React.Component {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    
    <div>
    <Text>HELLO WORLD</Text>
    </div>
    
    
    <StatusBar style='auto' />
  </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't add div element into react native app. Maybe you can add the pakage to use Div: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-div

Answer (score 2):

divs don't exist in react-native. You should use [View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) instead.

Answer (score 2):

React Native and React are related in their structure and logic, but the tags that you use will be different. The div tag on React Native is the View Component.

Instead of using:
`<div>Test</div>`

You should use
`<View><Text>Test<Text/></View>`

And some others:

```
<button> will be <Button>
<input> will be <Input>
<form> does not exist, you should use <View>
<ul><li>Test Item</li></ul> you should use <Flatlist /> or a [].map
```

Comment: Ah fair enough! Is there any other tags used in React/HTML that Native cant use? Like span/ h1/ p/ section  etc?

Comment: Actually, you'll not be able to use any of the HTML tags, but there's probably one component for each of it. For span, p, h1/2/3/4... you can use the Text component. And Text components accept other Text components as children. You can use it like this: `<Text>This is a test <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Text</Text></Text>`. You can see all React Native's components here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis

Answer (score 0):

## Like so but...

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <div>
       <Text>HELLO WORLD</Text>
      </div>   
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const div = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>{props.children}</View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

...you should get familiar with the components that are already built in. You are able to extend react native to support those tags but it is wierd to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use html element inside react native.
You may be use [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) to load html