# Event delegation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, event-delegation

Is it possible to create an event delegation in react native? We all know how it works in vanilla js, but I'm curious to know if it can be made in React Native

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="buttonClass">Click me</button>
  <button class="buttonClass">Click me</button>
  <!-- ... -->
  <button class="buttonClass">Click me</button>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('buttons')
    .addEventListener('click', event => { // Step 2
      if (event.target.className === 'buttonClass') { // Step 3
        console.log('Click!');
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you confusing react with react native? Since divs don't exist in React native. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443323/how-to-add-div-to-react-native

Comment: No, I'm not confusing react with react native. The code snippet in my question is just an example of delegation in vanilla js. I just want to know if I can make tihs in react native. For example, if I have 4 TouchableOpacity inside one View, but I don't want to type onPress prop 4 times. Is it possible in react native?